# Installing impatience in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

I tried installing impatience extension from terminal and got this output:-

```
sandip@sandip:~$ sudo apt-get install -y gnome-shell-extension-impatience
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gnome-shell-extension-impatience
sandip@sandip:~$ `enter code here`
```

I need to change animation speed in gnome so I tried to install this extension with a bit of googling work. But looks like it is not available(or maybe I nedd to change/add repository). Please help me install this extension. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/277/impatience/

Answer (score 0):

You can install and use `Extension Manager` and browse for required Extension(In your case 'Impatience')

Using the official repositories, you can easily install the extension manager
using;

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

Or using Ubuntu Software Center

After installing Extension Manager you will see installed Extensions on the **Installed** tab.

On the top, right next to installed you will find **Browse** where you can search for *impatience* and click on install.

To view,enable/disable,and remove extensions you can install **Extensions** software using

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
```

Its available in Ubuntu Software Center as well.

**Exception:**

If none of the above install works you can use Flatpak to install Extension-Manager

To install Flatpak;
refer [here](https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu)

To install Extension Manager using Flatpak;

```
flatpak install flathub com.mattjakeman.ExtensionManager
```